# THREE.js - Stop animation on click

Tags: three.js

```
    var thisframe;

    (function animate() {
        thisframe = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        renderer2.render(scene, cam2);
        terminate();
    })();

    function terminate() {
        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
        var myReq = requestAnimationFrame;

        var stoprender = document.getElementById( 'stoprenderbtn' );
        stoprender.onclick = function StopAnimation() {
            alert("thisbuttonworks"); # thisbuttonworks
        cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
        return; 
        };
    }
```

---

I want to stop the animation on click, but I haven't been successful yet.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Any console messages? Does the alert statement fire up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `cancelAnimationFrame()` with the same `requestID` that was return from the last `requestAnimationFrame()` call. You are actually not doing this in your code. Have a look at the following live example that demonstrates the basic workflow of stopping an animation loop.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

var requestID;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10 );
    camera.position.z = 1;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 0.2, 0.2, 0.2 );
    material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  
    document.getElementById( 'stopAnimation' ).addEventListener( 'click', stopAnimation );

}

function animate() {

    requestID = requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

function stopAnimation() {

    cancelAnimationFrame( requestID );

}
```

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
canvas {
   display: block;
}
button {
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<button id="stopAnimation">
Stop Animation
</button>
```